# Unable to login to private docker registry

Tags: authentication, ssl, https, docker, artifactory

I am trying to login to a private docker registry (Artifactory) using the following command

```
docker login myserver:myPort
Username: myUser
Password:
email: me@myServer.com
```

This fails with the following error

```
Error response from daemon: no successful auth challenge for https://myserver:myPort/v2/ - errors: []
```

Note that I have forced authentication for the docker repository that I am trying to access.
I am on Docker version 1.9 Here is the `dokcer info`

```
Containers: 0
Images: 20
Server Version: 1.9.1
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 20
 Dirperm1 Supported: false
Execution Driver: native-0.2
Logging Driver: json-file
Kernel Version: 3.13.0-24-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
CPUs: 4
Total Memory: 1.955 GiB
```

and docker version

```
Version:      1.9.1
API version:  1.21
Go version:   go1.4.2
Git commit:   a34a1d5
Built:        Fri Nov 20 13:12:04 UTC 2015
OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

server:
Version:      1.9.1
API version:  1.21
Go version:   go1.4.2
Git commit:   a34a1d5
Built:        Fri Nov 20 13:12:04 UTC 2015
OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

What does the error mean?

Comment: can you post `docker version` and `docker info`

Comment: added info to the question

Comment: I have had similar errors, upgrading to latest version fixed it

Comment: latest version of Docker?

Comment: Isnt 1.9.1 the latest release version?

Answer (score 0):

Can you make sure that the CA certificate is in the following directory on the host you're trying to log in from?

```
  /etc/docker/certs.d/<registry-server>:<registry-port>/
```

Comment: yes it is. On a side note why does a CA certificate need to be identified on each docker cleint?